# JQuery .load and $this

Tags: jquery

I have a small problem with JQuery .load that´s driving me nuts - I am quite sure it is simple, but I have been staring at it for too long now :)

I have the following in a `.ready(function() {`

```
$('.content_s').load('url/path/aspxpage?dataid='+$(this).attr('data'));
```

and 1 or more `.content_s` classed div with a `data="data"` section, but I cannot get the data attr - i just get undefined, regardless of the number of divs or what I set as data. The aspxpage gets called alright, just not with the data attr.

As mentioned, I think I have stared myself blind on this, so any suggestions would be most welcome.

Regards

Comment: $('.content_s').load('url/path/aspxpage?dataid='+$('.content_s').attr('data'));

Comment: @madflow `$('.content_s').attr('data')` will only return the first `.content_s` element's data.

Comment: `data="data"` is not the proper way to write a data attribute, you must use `data-key="value"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.each` in such case:

```
$('.content_s').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.load('url/path/aspxpage?dataid='+$this.attr('data'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In this context, $(this) is not the targeted div.

Try this:

`$('.content_s').each(function() { $(this).load('url/path/aspxpage?dataid='+$(this).attr('data')) });`